# My class component is not displaying anything

Tags: reactjs, class, components

So, I just started with react and i'm having troubles displaying my class component in the browser.
Here's my code...

```
import React, { component } from 'react'

class Hello extends component {
render() {
return <h1>class component</h1>
}
}
export default Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `component`, it should be `Component` (in PascalCase)